# Protect complex object against Mass Assignment in ASP.NET MVC using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can I protect against mass assignment using an object with a large list of properties and which inherits a base model. Using `[Bind(Include = "property names")]` seems messy and hard to read.

```
public class Employee : Benefits
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Salary { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int Hours { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsPartTime { get; set; }   
}

public class Benefits
{
    public bool Health { get; set; }
    public bool Vision { get; set; }
    public bool Dental { get; set; }
    public bool Life { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddEmployee(Employee model)
{
    //do some work on model
    return View("Home");
}
```

How should I write the `AddEmployee` method to protect from mass assignment?

And, do I need to protect the properties of both `Employee` and `Benefits`?

Comment: Sorry, but what's _mass assignment_?

Comment: Not directly related to your question but I would rethink `Employee : Benefits` relationship. An Employee *has* benefits, therefor composition would be a more appropriate choice instead of inheritance.

Comment: @Igor Yeah those are just some classes I made up.  It's just an example.

Comment: @Flydog57 Google is your friend. :)

Comment: You can use a DTO to limit the model exposure. Example: `public class EmployeeDTO { public string LastName {get; set;} }`

Comment: https://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/11/complete-guide-to-mass-assignment-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Comment: Ah, googling can be useful, but it's the question asker's responsibility to provide the information the answerer needs. Consider making the first use of "mass assignment" a link. I've even worked to mitigate _mass assignment_ vulnerabilities in the past, but not in, perhaps 5 or 6 years.

Comment: @Flydog57 Should I also make "inherit" and "properties" links, too.  In case people don't know what those are.